# Autolayout Same width and height for View?

Tags: ios, ipad, autolayout, ios9

I have a viewcontroller with one view.I need to show the view ipad portrait and landscape view with same width and height at center of the screen and edge of right.I need look like below screenshots

[image] [image]

its possible in autolayout how to do that with constraints?

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2 learn from this tutorials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I hope this will help you out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PppK4.png)

Check out the constraints in above image and i hope it will be helpful to you

Answer (score 2):

Use the pin tool on the UITextFields to set top and leading values. For the grey view use the align tool to set it vertically centre and the pin tool to set it trailing space to the edge of the containing view. You can also set the height and width of the grey view in the pin tool if they need to be the same.

Answer (score 2):

For `UITextField`s

1. Set Leading , top, bottom values

For `UIView`

1. Set Vertically Centre constraint
2. Set Trailing space to '0' , so that it will be always vertically centred and attached to the right border of the parent View.